# Default constructor cannot handle exception type IOException thrown by implicit super constructor. Must define an explicit constructor

Tags: java

Есть класс:

```
package AC;

import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Getip {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("ip");
    }

    public static String getip() throws IOException {
        URL whatismyip = new URL("http://checkip.amazonaws.com");
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(whatismyip.openStream()));
        return in.readLine();
    } 
}
```

В другом классе пытаюсь вызвать переменную:

```
Getip ip = new Getip();
String ipept = ip.getip();
```

Во второй строке высвечивает проблему:

> Default constructor cannot handle exception type IOException thrown by implicit super constructor. Must define an explicit constructor

Как её можно исправить?

Comment: 1. Зачем вы вызываете статический метод через объект? 2. Где и как вы планируете обрабатывать исключение `IOException`, которое пробрасывает вызываемый вами метод `getip`?

Comment: 1. пока точно не знаю, как умею так и пробую)
2. я не планирую обрабатывать, мне нужно получить значение которое вычисляется в классе

Comment: Есть три варианта: 1. Обрабатывать `IOException` внутри метода `getip` с помощью try-catch и не пробрасывать `(throws`) его. 2. Обернуть вызов метода `getip` (`String ipept = ip.getip()`) в try-catch. 3. Пробрасывать `IOException` дальше (с помощью `throws` у метода/конструктора, в котором вызывается метод `getip`). Ничего не делать - это не вариант.